# Can I pass a parameter to a F# FAKE build script?

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I'm just getting started with FAKE. I really like the idea. In the tutorials the set the build and deploy directories.

```
// Directories
let buildDir  = "./build/"
let testDir   = "./test/"
let deployDir = "./deploy/"
```

and then later reference those which is fine, but is it possible to pass that as a parameter? Maybe to as Task where I can use it later?

Comment: Command-line parameter? Or function parameter?

Comment: Maybe with =?> operator and hasBuildParam option.

Comment: Was waning to pass a commandline param to the script or task

Comment: Passing command line parameters makes perfect sense: i.e. passing push target and credentials for private nuget feeds from CI (gitlab in our case)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Something like this should work.

From the command-line:

```
"..\packages\Fake.3.7.5\tools\Fake.exe" "build.fsx" dir=my/custom/dir/
```

In the build.fsx script:

```
let buildDir = getBuildParamOrDefault "dir" "./build/"
```

That will look for the dir parameter being passed in, and use it if it's assigned, otherwise it will default to ./build/

Comment: And for For FAKE 5 use Environment.environVarOrDefault(...) in http://fake.build/apidocs/v5/fake-core-environment.html

Comment: I'm using FAKE 5 and using environVarOrFail and it always fails when I try to pass in the script arguments as described by danmiser.

Comment: This answer doesn't align with my experience and the answer provided to my github issue. https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/issues/2125#issuecomment-427684505

Comment: This solution did not work for me on Windows. The @PiotrWolkowski solution worked (`-e` option need to be specified).

Answer (score 2):

Non of the above fully worked for me. Below an adjusted solution.
The console command needs to be run with the `-e` flag:

```
"..\fake.exe" "build.fsx" -e dir=sample/directory
```

The build script is using `Environment.environVarOrDefault "dir" "default\directory"`:

```
let buildDir = Environment.environVarOrDefault "dir" "default\directory"
```

`Environment.environVar` can also be used if no alternative is provided.

Finally the build script has to run with `Target.runOrDefaultWithArguments`. It will fail if it's executed with `Target.runOrDefault`:

```
// start build
Target.runOrDefaultWithArguments "DefaultBuildTarget"
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer accepted doesn't seem to work for FAKE 5.

You will want to set the environment variable before running the script.

```
dir=my/custom/dir/ ./fake.sh run build.fsx
```

As linked in the comments above.

http://www.github.com/fsharp/FAKE/issues/2125#issuecomment-427684505

Comment: That only works in a unixoid shell, though. It's painful to impossible to achieve on Windows.