# Specifying build parameters to FAKE

Tags: f#-fake

I am essentially asking for an update to date answer to the already answered question: [Can I pass a parameter to a F# FAKE build script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267601/can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-f-fake-build-script)

Here is build.fsx

```
let revisionNumber  = getBuildParamOrDefault "rev" "123"

Target "Log" (fun _ -> 
    trace ("Revision Number: " + revisionNumber)
)

RunTargetOrDefault "Log"
```

Output running `Fake.exe .\build.fsx`:

[image]

Perfect!

Output running `Fake.exe .\build.fsx rev=456` (as suggested by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26597179/2382536):

Starts with

[image]

But at the bottom gives the correct result:

[image]

What format do I need to pass the parameters in to get rid of the warning message?

Answer (score 1):

Passing parameters is done using the `--envvar` parameter. Until recently you can just add parameters in a way you did after the build target but not anymore. I believe this was changed in order not to confuse build parameters with (optional) build target name.

So, try this:

```
fake build.fsx Push --envvar rev 456
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to share the link to the [official documentation:](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/commandline.html)

#### TLDR:

You can either use

```
--envvar [-ev] <name:string> <value:string>
```

to set a variable to a custom value, or

```
--envflag [-ef] <name:string>
```

to set a variable to true, or

```
--fsiargs --debug+ buildscript.fsx someArg1 anotherArg2
```

to pass all arguments (including build script name, importent!) direcly to [fsi.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/fsharp-interactive/fsharp-interactive-options)